# jquery datatable - How to use render function get data from another column

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have add button in each row ,but I want to check if info column data is N/A, then not shown the button, I have try to set render as below in my code ,but it's not work

```
{
    "targets": -1,
    "data": null,
    "render": function ( data, type, row ) 
    {
        if (row.info != 'N/A') {
        return "<button href='" + row.index() + "' class='btn btn-info'>View</button>"
        } else { return "" }
     }
    }                    
}
```

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.
Willing to post any more information if it will help.

Comment: "render": function ( data, type, row )
           {
             if (row.info!='N/A')
              return "<button href='"+row.index()+"' class='btn btn-info'>View</button>"

           }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/udgp3x9o/26/)

```
"render": function(data, type, full, meta ) {
    if (full.info != 'N/A') {
        return "<button href='" + row.index() + "' class='btn btn-info'>View</button>"
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Render is documented here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

You aren't using the same name of arguments documented there, but in the examples, you would use `full` to access all of the available columns and `data` is the current column.  I'm not sure where you got `field` from.  So data from `info` would be accessed at `full.info`.

An example being:

```
"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
  return '<a href="'+data+'">' + full.info + '</a>';
}
```